# using enableAutoManage() in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places-api, google-api-client

Is there another way to connect Google API client?

I use auto complete places and I have to use this code some where in MYFRAGMENT

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this).build();
```

My problem with

```
enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this).build();
```

I can't deal with it because when I replace `this` with `getActivity()` I have many problem with casting

thanks for help and sorry if this question is silly.

Comment: Which "this" are you replacing? Just the first one? Is your activity a FragmentActivity?

Comment: first "this" in enableAutoManage() I have an error and I fix it by catsing to  FragmentActivity but when run the app it stopped

Comment: No my MainActivity is not FragmentActivity

Comment: @Hamza can you please tell me the type of GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID. as enableAutoManage accept int but our google api key is string.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you want to use `enableAutoManage` then you must make your activity extend `FragmentActivity`. The callbacks it makes are required for the automatic management of the `GoogleApiClient` to work. So the easiest solution is to add `extends FragmentActivity` to your activity. Then your cast would not fail and cause the app to crash at runtime.

The alternate solution is to manage the api client yourself. You would remove the `enableAutoManage` line from the builder, and make sure you `connect`/`disconnect` from the client yourself. The most common place to do this is `onStart()`/`onStop()`. Something like...

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this).build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Is it really just connect/disconnect? By looking at GoogleApiClient sources, it seems to do something more than that. I cannot tell for sure, because it's hard to read their obfuscated code. I just don't want to extend from `FragmentActivity`, because my app does not support old API levels anyway. Extending from `FragmentActivity` also brings more issues (with animations, different FragmentManager and LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks), so I'd better just stay at `Activity`. But I want to mimic exact behavior of `enableAutoManage()`.

Comment: The docs for [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) suggest that in addition to the start and stop behavior, it attempts to handle some connection errors also. If you don't enableAutoManager then you have to add this logic yourself in the `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` you add to your client. It's hard to say what specific actions they take in these cases.

Comment: And the thing is: the example code provided by Google is using `AppCompatActivity` and not a Fragment but still using then `enableAutoManage`. How can this be?

Comment: I am not sure which example code you are referring to. Did you mean to say they use an `AppCompatActivity` instead of a `FragmentActivity`? This is possible because `AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Stupidiest tight coupling ever. Is Google really serious about this api client class?

Comment: I would definitely recommend checking out the new GeoDataClient class instead. It lets you skip the hassle of dealing with the GoogleApiClient class. (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataClient)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for late reply but rather than extending FragmentActivity you can extend AppCompatActivity...

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

.....

```
mCredentialsApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this,this)
                    .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your fragment is running in a FragmentActivity, or AppCompatActivity you can do something like this:

```
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage((FragmentActivity) getActivity() /* FragmentActivity */, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    // your code here
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to accepted answer except, I use second signature of Builder so that connectionFailedListener is also send to the constructor.

Followed by `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` and `mGoogleApiClient.disconnect()` in `onStart()` and `onStop()` respectively

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this /*context*/ , this /*connectedListener*/, this /**connectionFailedListener/)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .build();
}
```