# Google places API, get user addresses

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have been struggling with *Google Places API*, I need to use the Address API.

I used the *autoComplete* and the *placePicker* APIs just fine, for some reason the Address API is not working.

I have tried looking through this https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/identity/intents/Address
but I couldn't figure out how to use the `addApi()` for the Address API.

If someone could provide some example code or something to get me started it would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to get user's address by getting thier gps co-ordinates ?

Comment: No, i just want to call `requestUserAddress()` so it prompts the user to share his addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the Address API you need to add an option like this:

```
    Address.AddressOptions options = new  Address.AddressOptions(AddressConstants.Themes.THEME_LIGHT);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Address.API, options)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
```

Then you can request the address:

```
UserAddressRequest request = UserAddressRequest.newBuilder().build();
        Address.requestUserAddress(mGoogleApiClient, request,
                REQUEST_CODE);
```

And then you get the result:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    UserAddress userAddress = UserAddress.fromIntent(data);
                    //DO SOMETHING
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    break;
                default:
                    //NO ADDRESS
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

And add this to your gradle:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, there is a however and issue.
I need to implement the API code in a `FragmentActivity` so i can make a call to the `enableAutoManage()`. Also, implementing your code in an `Activity` returns "An Activity must be used for Address APIs" Exception.

Comment: @MazenElian you're right, i don't know why Address API doesn't like enableAutomanage(), in others API works fine, you can find a workaround in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622906/using-enableautomanage-in-fragment