# Android: Google Address API

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33057472/4070848) working.  So far as I can tell, the user can choose from their existing addresses (not sure where from, maybe contacts?).  I've spent hours trying to get it working, but can't.  After `Address.requestUserAddress()` is called, it just returns an error code straight away to `onActivityResult()`, with no picker or dialog shown and no actual results.  Anyone got some working code to share?

What I'm trying to achieve is a pre-existing way of allowing the user to select from a list of favourite locations ([not apparently possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37157108/4070848)), with a second best option being to allow the user to select an address from another source, hence trying the method in the first-linked page.

Comment: // Google Play Services  try this dependencies {
    
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'  }

Comment: I was already using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'` which I believe just picks out the bit from `play-services` that is needed (e.g. I also have `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'`).  Still, no address picker or anything is displayed... just goes straight to `onActivityResult()`.  In any case, what sort of interface is it?  A list of what addresses, from where?  I can't even work that out.