# How to build correctly the GooglePlacesApi?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-places-api, google-places

I'm new in android. I'm using the GooglePlaces Api in my app. I already have a key and the GooglePlace service enabled.

According to Google documentation, the correct way to build the GooglePlaces

`mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();`

But looking for code examples on other webpages, I found:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
        .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
        .build();
```

What is the "clientId" parameter? How do i get it? Is the same as the Google Client OAuth 2.0?

Comment: You can use Android ReactiveLocation [Android-ReactiveLocation](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation)

> Small library that wraps Google Play Services API in brilliant RxJava
> Observables reducing boilerplate to minimum.

Answer (score 0):

YES.

To create an OAuth 2.0 client ID in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project), do the following:

1. Open the `Credentials` page.
2. Click `Create new Client ID`.
3. Select the appropriate Application Type for your project and enter any additional information required. If this is your first time creating a client ID, besides being able to select your application type, you can configure your consent screen by clicking the Consent Screen button. You will not get a prompt to configure your consent screen again after you do it the first time.
4. Click `Create Client ID`

To deactivate the client ID, click the Delete button below the appropriate table on the Credentials page.

**EDITS:**

Don't forgot to add `onStart()` and `onStop()` in code:-

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: I got a client ID like this:

1234567891234-bq5ncqm2gckhj8melh7q3deedk38hapi.apps.googleusercontent.com

what is the clientID (int parameter) in the builder? 
.enableAutoManage(this, /* clientId */, this)

The first 13 numbers are too large for a integer type.

Comment: can you check [using enableAutoManage() in fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622906/using-enableautomanage-in-fragment) ?