# Issues with Google Play Leaderboards

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-api, leaderboard

I am having issues in understanding Google Developers Guides:

[Google Developers GUIDE Add Leaderboards](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards#before_you_begin)

I have created a game using LibGDX, so I have a Core module and Android Module. In Android Module I only have `AndroidLauncher` Class which extends `AndroidApplication`.

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements ActionResolver, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    ActionResolverAndroid actionResolverAndroid;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionResolverAndroid = new ActionResolverAndroid(this);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new PepeAdventures(actionResolverAndroid), config);
    }
```

I have created another class in Android module called `ActionResolverAndroid`.

```
public class ActionResolverAndroid implements ActionResolver {

    Handler handler;
    Context context;
    GoogleApiClient client;

    public ActionResolverAndroid(Context context){
        handler = new Handler();
        this.context = context;

        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                 .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .build();

    }
}
```

All this I did according to instruaction (as I understood them) by Google Developers.

Now I have issues:

- How to display LeaderBoards, when it is GameOver ?

> In my Core module, I have `GameOverScreen` class which currently pops, when
>   the player dies. Now I would like to post also LeaderBoards. I dont
>   know how to do this.

- Google API Client requires Fragment Activity when I try to build it in my ActionResolverAndroid class. But I do not have any FragmentActivity in my Project - what should I pass here?

  ```
  client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
          .enableAutoManage(/*fragmentActivity*/, /*OnConnFailedListener*/)
          .addApi(Drive.API)
          .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
          .build();
  ```

I also tried to find some other tutorials on how to do this, but all are out-dated or very hard to find (especially when using LibGDX as Project Setup).

Please help me or give me advice on what to do.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Google api but why do you need `.enableAutoManage`? You only need the `Plus.API` (to login) and `Game.API` (for the leaderboards) in the `client` for leaderboards. I transformed the standard NumberGame example into a working LibGDX game have a look, maybe it helps.  https://github.com/madmenyo/NumberGame

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out.

Comment: Here is something that can help you with the `fragmentActivity` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622906/using-enableautomanage-in-fragment