# Is there any way to enableAutoManage in Google Sign In when we are not extending it by fragment or appcompat Activity?

Tags: android, google-signin

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java#L59-L64

You can see this code for the refrence for the guide available in the google developer ... but i want it without any appcompat or fragment activity extending it

Answer (score 0):

It requires `FragmentActivity` reference to automate lifecycle management of the `GoogleApiClient`. However, you can handle that lifecycle on your own. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30627422/1432752) answer.

Comment: what if i dont extend it by fragmentActivity but only by AppcompatActivity ... ?

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`